# in lunchtime or at lunchtime

Tags: grammar

How say correctly?

I want buy a micro usb type b connector **in lunchtime**.
I want buy a micro usb type b connector **at lunchtime**.

Answer (score 1):

At is better.

Examples:

He visited his friend **at lunchtime.**
He spoke to her **at dinner.**
They laughed together about it **at breakfast.**

Using **during** would be better than in.

Answer (score 1):

Lunchtime (Noun), according to [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lunchtime):

> The time in the middle of the day when lunch is eaten.

Example sentence:

> At lunchtime - I will meet you at lunchtime.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe, both are correct

She likes to meet clients **at lunchtime.**

We sometimes play ping-pong **in lunchtime**.